# Jquery ajax long polling error- Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, long-polling

I am just trying ajax long polling for a simple chat application. Here is the js code. Its works well in Firefox, But when it comes to **chrome**, the appended text is repeated. I cant figure out what the error is.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#chatText').keydown(function(event) 
 {  
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "http://example.com/Private.pl",
             data: $('form#chatText').serialize(),
             success: function(data) // same data posted by client to server
            {
            $('#chatText')[0].reset();
            $("#chatLog").append(data);
            $("#chatLog").scrollTop(999999) 
            poll();
            }
      })
    event.preventDefault();
    }         
 });
});

function poll() {
$.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: 'http://example.com/Private.pl', 
             data: $('form#chatText2').serialize(),
             success: function(msg) // other users message from server
            {
            $('#chatLog').append(msg);
            $('#chatLog').scrollTop(999999);
            }, 
        complete: poll,
        timeout: 500000
    });
 }
```

Here is the HTML snippet

```
<div id='chatLog' class='text-Area'></div>
<textarea name='message'></textarea>
<form id='chatText' method='post'>
<input type='submit' hidden>
</form>
<form id='chatText2' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='client' value='0'>   
<input type='submit' hidden>
</form>
```

Comment: can you post the relevant html as well?

Comment: Hi anurupr I have posted the html snippet.

Comment: can you post the values of `msg` for both calls?

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate, its not the error.. i changed that msg to data.. However the same error persists in chrome but not in firefox..

Comment: You could try setting short timeouts on poll. E.g. `setTimeout(poll, 1000)` in both places where you call the poll function.

Comment: anyway you could create a fiddle?

Comment: Ya. It did helped. I used it along with request.abort() function. Its not repeating anymore. But i am losing some messages. It cancels some requests after fetching the data from server.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. In firefox, whenever i type a new text and submit, former polling requests are aborted and a new polling is started. But in chrome, whenever i type a new message a new polling request is added with the old hanging requests. So server is responding every polling requests with same message at same time. The error is calling of **poll()** method everytime i send a new message..